# How to download a file from DEP using same file path where the Excel with the VBA is located?

Tags: vba, filepath, sap-gui

I hope my question makes sense. What I am trying to do is find a way for other users to execute this script I created without needing to write down the File Path within the workbook.

Basically, you would be able to move the Macro from desktop to any other folder and it would execute normally.

I am stuck in the highlighted line, with the error message:

Run time error '613': the method got and invalid argument.

Does anyone have an idea on why is this happening? Note that this is just the beginning of the code, exactly to where it crashes.

EDIT: Solved by Scriptman. I post the full working code below.

```
'Set dimmensions
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim maxi As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim folder As String

  Set GuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")  'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
  Set App = GuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
  Set Con = App.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
  Set session = Con.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection
  Set sessioninfo = session.Info

'Create new definitions
    Set ws = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro")
    i = 2
    maxi = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    invtyp1 = "Proforma - Normal Invoice"
    invtyp2 = "Proforma - Title Invoice"
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    folder = wb.Path

'This line marks the beginning of the loop. Ergo, the things that must be done over and over again until the stablished end
        Do While i < maxi + 1

'Enter VA03 to copy the PO number
    session.StartTransaction "va03"
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
    Cells(i, 2) = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/txtVBKD-BSTKD").Text

'Go to VF01 to Create the Billing Document
    session.StartTransaction "vf01"
        If Cells(10, 5).Value = invtyp2 Then
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cmbRV60A-FKART").Key = "YF6"
        End If
        If Cells(10, 5).Value = invtyp1 Then
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cmbRV60A-FKART").Key = "YF5"
        End If
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMV60ATCTRL_ERF_FAKT/ctxtKOMFK-VBELN[0,0]").Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 11
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

'Go to VF03 to create a Spool Request
    session.StartTransaction "vf03"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[11]").Select
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLVMSGTABCONTROL").GetAbsoluteRow(0).Selected = True
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[37]").Press
'Place here the code for printing
    session.FindById("wnd[2]/usr/chkSSFPP-TDIMMED").Selected = False
    session.FindById("wnd[2]/usr/chkSSFPP-TDNEWID").Selected = True
    session.FindById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[86]").Press
    session.FindById("wnd[1]").Close
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").Press

' Copying the spool request into the workbook
    session.StartTransaction "sp01"
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 8
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[3,3]").SetFocus
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[3,3]").CaretPosition = 7
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 2
    Sheets("Relevant Data").Cells(i, 7).Value = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtTSP01_SP0R-RQID_CHAR").Text
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 2
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").Press

'Printing the spool request
    session.StartTransaction "zv145"
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtSPOOLNO").Text = Sheets("Relevant Data").Cells(i, 7).Value
    
        If Cells(4, 5).Text = Cells(1, 1).Text Then
''        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_FILE").Text = Cells(2, 5).Value & "\" & Cells(i, 1).Value
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_FILE").Text = """folder""" & "\" & Cells(i, 1).Value
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").Press
''        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Cells(2, 5).Value
        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = folder
        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "Proforma - " & Cells(i, 1).Value & ".pdf"
'        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").CaretPosition = 13
        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").SetFocus
        session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
        
        Else
''        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_FILE").Text = Cells(2, 5).Value & "\" & Cells(i, 2).Value
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_FILE").Text = """folder""" & "\" & Cells(i, 2).Value
        session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").Press
''        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Cells(2, 5).Value
        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "Proforma - " & Cells(i, 2).Value & ".pdf"
'        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").CaretPosition = 13
        session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").SetFocus
        session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
        End If

'    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_FILE").SetFocus
'    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_FILE").CaretPosition = 28
'    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
'    AppActivate "Converting SAPscript (OTF) or ABAP List Spool Job to PDF"
'    SendKeys "{F8}"
'    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))
'    AppActivate "Save as"
'    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
'    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

i = i + 1

Loop

MsgBox "All documents generated." & vbNewLine & "Please check your destination folder."

End Sub
```

Comment: You can try following: session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_FDEST").Text = folder & "clientZV115.csv"; I.e. without a slash

Comment: Thanks for the help ScriptMan, sorry for coming late to you. It still does not work (throws the same error) and I made modifications on the script, so now it looks different. The error persists on the line  session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_FILE").Text = folder ' & "\" & Cells(i, 2).Value and as you can see I tried writing just 'folder' but SAP still does not get it, maybe I am missing a Dim somehwere?

Comment: What does the content of the variable folder look like? Could it be that the string contains spaces?

Comment: Hi Scriptman, do you mean how does the path look like? Is this one: C:\Users\XXXXX\OneDrive - XXXXX\BoxMigrated-Private\Proformas, Facturas, PL, OA maybe the commas or OneDrive are messing it up?

Comment: In this case I would try it as follows:    ... = """folder""" & "\" & cells(i,2).value or ... = chr(34) & folder & chr(34) & "\" & cells(i,2).value

Comment: Hi Scritpman, thank you. The first option made it run. By any chance do you have a blog? You are a quite active member of the community and for what I gather you have vast knowledge about programming in general. Would be pleased to watch or read your tutorials if so.

Comment: Scirptman, sorry, but I double checked and the files are being downloaded in C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive - Diageo\Documents\SAP\SAP GUI instead of C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive - Diageo\BoxMigrated-Private\Proformas, Facturas, PL, OA The file is located on the later, any idea why this might be happening? Tried with the chr(34) & folder & chr(34) & "\" & cells(i,2).value but I receive the original error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see from a distance why that is the case. Please incorporate the following and check the paths. Maybe you will see something. for example: ... folder = wb.Path and msgbox folder, vbOKonly or ... session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_FILE").Text = """folder""" & "\" & Cells(i, 2).Value and msgbox "break", vbOKonly